# Magento + Calll event after submit action in grid layout

Tags: magento

Below is grid layout
 [image]

Which event is all after submit action.

I am using below event

```
 <custom_effect_save_after>
            <observers>
                <custom_effect_save_after_handler>
                    <class>Company_Custom_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>customMethod</method>
                </custom_effect_save_after_handler>
            </observers>
        </custom_effect_save_after>
```

But this event is working only save button. but i want to use an event on submit button.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if there is any event. Probably None. But Why you want observer where you can do it in your controller. Its your own controller so you can edit/customize it.

Comment: @KingshukDeb : yes this is second solution to use dispatch event but it would be good if magento give an event like i used custom_modal_save_after  on save data